# generate an arbitrary angled contour from 3D data points

Tags: python, matlab, data-visualization

I am wondering if there is a way to generate 2d contour plots from a set of 3D data points using either python or matlab? The 3D data points create a roughly spherical shape and the contour would represent the outer border of this spheroid on different planes angled from 0 to 180 degrees

I am thinking one way is to generate a 3D surface from the pointcloud by using numpy.meshgrid and then using plot_surface. However, I also do not find a way to take angled slices out of the interpolated 3D data to obtain a contour.

Ideas very welcome!
thanks
Jesse

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but you might want to check out the Matlab functions `contour` or `contourf` for this?

Comment: Now that sounds like an interesting problem!  I'm not sure I understand all of your requirements, though - are you after a surface that goes through every point, or a 'bounding' surface that never goes concave (as if you deflated a balloon around those points)?

Comment: This site would be more appropriate for this question:
http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Fraukje I looked at the Matlab contour functions, but according to the documentation only contours on the xy plane can be generated?

Comment: @MikeSadler I have tried to outline graphically what I am trying to do, :) hopefully this explains a bit better http://imagebin.org/270775

Comment: @Jesse RJ Yes it has a 3D input and generates a 2D plot, I thought that was what you asked for?

Comment: @Fraukje ah, so in order to get contours at arbitrary angles I would rotate the surface object and use 'contour' with Z = 0 always?

Comment: Trying to create a surface going through a set of points as shown in your picture would be very tricky - and potentially ambiguous depending on the quality of your input (you might get non-manifold results, etc).  The only practical way I can think of if to 'walk' across the points, building up triangular patches as you go.  This would be very sensitive to the quality of the data - you might need to 'clean' the points to remove those which are too close together.  You could also try the gaming forums - surfaces, points and intersections are their bread and butter.

Comment: Honestly, I would never have figured your goal out without the pictures. The pictures show a strongly non-convex shape however, while your question implies a roughly spherical shape. Which is it? A convex shape will be much simpler.

Comment: In any event, I would generate the surface with a convex hull. An alpha shape would be my choice if the surface is not convex. Then slice through the set of triangles so produced. A planar slice through a triangle will produce an edge. So the result will be a polygon, i.e., a piecewise linear 1-manifold in your 3-d space.

Comment: @JesseRJ No, the colours would show you the Z-values. But there's a lot about this question which I don't understand too well, so it could be that I am understanding you wrongly. But if you really are looking to obtain a contour I think `contour` is the way to go.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your help. I was actually able to use matlab to create a 3D surface of my data and then use contour to extract a Z=0 contour. I was then going to start working on using contourslice to get other angles however I realized that I really should be extracting the contours directly from my data and not from the matlab surface which is automatically interpolated and is a visual approximation of my data. Ill have to start looking at how to create my own interpolation to create a contour from sparse spherical data. :) cheers